# Как вызвать функцию ассемблера из C?

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер

function.asm:

```
.data
strink:
    .string "It works!"
    len = . - strink

globl functin

functin:
    // int write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
    mov x0, 1
    ldr x1, =strink
    ldr x2, =len
    mov w8, #64
    svc #0
```

А как эту функцию вызвать из C, C++ кода?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
// что тут должно быть?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Инструкцию `ret` в конец функции добавьте. В .c файле допишите `extern void functin();` и вызов -- `functin()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо хотя бы поправить явные ошибки.

```
globl functin
```

тут явно должно быть вот так

```
.text
.global functin
```

то есть, саму функцию надо поместить в секцию для кода, а то в секции для даты оно не исполняется.

Я не знаю ассемблера от arm поэтому, пока удалим все тело и напишем просто ret в конце и это будет все тело. Нам же потестировать нужно.

Также напишем makefile, а то ручками собирать лень

У меня получилось вот так

```
all: main.o file.o
        gcc -ggdb main.o file.o -o result

main.o: main.c
        gcc -ggdb main.c -c -o main.o

file.o: file.asm
        as -g file.asm -o file.o

clean:
        rm *.o
        rm result
```

Теперь сделаем вызов. Наша функция пока ничего не принимает и ничего не возвращает. Ее сигнатура для си будет вот такая

extern void functin();

и теперь можно позвать `functin();`

Все, теперь оно как минимум компилируется, линкуется и работает.

Что делает именно Ваш код - я не знаю, поэтому, угадать сигнатуру мне сложно.

upd, как выглдяит main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void functin();
int main() {
// что тут должно быть?
    functin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили

Comment: 1)Ну хоть угадали, что я на aarch64 ассемблере все написал)

Comment: 2)Спасибо за Makefile

Comment: Саму сигнатуру можно в си файле перед main написать - компилятор не будет ругаться.

Comment: gcc пишет, что функция functin не объявлена...

Comment: добавил пример main.c

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412305/478514

Comment: Оно там подсказывает компилировать с параметром -fPIC

Comment: c'mon, я не библиотеку компилирую... Да и параметр -fPIC не помог, ошибка та же

Comment: UPD: поменял платформу с Android (Termux) на Kali Nethunter. Код отрабатывает двойственно: он выполняется и одновременно возвращает ошибку Illegal instruction...

Comment: Illegal instruction - это явно ошибка в ассемблерном коде, я бы поубирал по максимуму кода в ассемблере и попытался для начала скомпилировать и получить стабильный результат.

Comment: мне кажется, оно ругается на отсутствие выхода. Но в том и проблема, это функция, а не полноценный скрипт на ассемблере...

Comment: UPD: надо было возвращать результат через ret. Странновато для void функции, но ладно...

Comment: А я о ret говорил. Даже для void функции он строго нужен.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ~ $ make all
        GCC    main.o file.o
ld.lld: error: relocation R_AARCH64_ABS64 cannot be used against local symbol; recompile with -fPIC
>>> defined in asm.o
>>> referenced by print.asm:14
>>>               asm.o:(.text+0x18)
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 1
```

Comment: Не нужно публиковать это как ответ